# windows not accepting static dns from mikrotik

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, mikrotik

I have mikrotik on which I set up static DNS entries for my network. Form linuxes everything works correctly even from one of windows computers (windows 7) but from other windows computers I can't resolve dns entries. I don't know where to find the issue. Please can you suggest where should I start?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use "device.lan" instead of "device" in your static DNS entries

Comment: This works! It can be any names but it needs a dot in between.

Answer (score 1):

Some advises:

1. Try to use on windows `ipconfig /flushdns`
2. On Mikrotik `/ip dns cache flush`
3. On Mikrotik open/allow TCP/UPD 53 port
4. Check that the windows instances has correct DNS (mikrotik IP)